# QT widgets, rounded selected corner only

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I can set a QT QPushButton to rounded button by setting "border-radius" in style sheet, however i just want to set only the right edge (top and bottom right) corner of the button to rounded. How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried setting `border-top-right-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `border-top-right-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius` in style sheet.